# How can I transform a jquery object into a php array?

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

I created a jquery object via `$("input").serializeArray();`

This is my output:

```
0: Object { name: "id", value: "9" }
1: Object { name: "name", value: "Fred" }
2: Object { name: "quantity", value: "1" }
```

I send this object via ajax to my php page. There I get it via `$_POST['myarray']`. The output is:

```
[0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(2) "id"
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "9"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "name"
    ["value"]=>
    string(14) "Fred"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "quantity"
    ["value"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
```

But the output I would need is:

```
      array(3) {
        ["id"]=>
        string(1) "9"
        ["name"]=>
        string(1) "Fred"
        ["quantity"]=>
        string(1) "1"
      }
```

Comment: `$("input").serializeArray();` did not create the object you'd like. It created an array of objects. Consolidate those objects on the client side.

Comment: You can change js or make array by php. What are you prefer?

Comment: Oh ok, I understand. The problem is the object I created. Yes, I will try to figure out how I can created the object properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the required data structure in PHP you need to send a single object from your JS code in this format:

```
{ 
  id: "9",
  name: "Fred",
  quantity: "1" 
}
```

To do that you can build a new object using the keys of the objects within the current array, like this:

```js
var serializedForm = [
  { name: "id", value: "9" },
  { name: "name", value: "Fred" },
  { name: "quantity", value: "1" }
];
  
var o = {};
serializedForm.forEach((k) => {
  o[k.name] = k.value;
});

console.log(o);
```

Answer (score 2):

On the server side, you can pick the key/value pairs in a loop and create the array format you desire:

```
$formObj = $_POST['myarray'];
$myObj = array();

foreach($formObj as $array){
    $myObj[$array["name"]] = $array["value"];
}

var_dump($myObj); // New object with key/value pair
```